# What does it mean when you have a variable like access$002 in Java?

Tags: java, decompiling

I have a java jar I have decompiled with permission of the original developer that we are to use until they can get us a copy of the source code. I have run into a member of a class that looks like the following:

```
Classname.access$002(Param1, Param2);
```

Classname is correct, but the *access$002* does not look right (there are a few others like this except with the names *access$204* and with other numbers appended to the end), and I am wondering if this means anything in Java or if it is because the decompile operation was incomplete.

I am using JD-GUI to decompile the classes.

It is also worth mentioning that there are no methods with the same signature as the *access$002* method does, at least in the class Classname.

Comment: These links may help: http://www.retrologic.com/innerclasses.doc7.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167326/java-class-name-containing-dollar-sign - the first link mentions that they may be methods created as part of internal access classes to help the JVM understand the grouping of classes that can access some member.

Comment: The technical term is synthetic accessor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `access$XXX` methods are calls from inner non-static classes to members of the nesting class.

```
public class DummyDummy {

private int x = 0;
private Inner i = new Inner();
private int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a+b+x;
}

private class Inner {
    void doIt() {
        System.out.println(
         // Here, DummyDummy.access$0(DummyDummy, int, int) is called 
         // which calls DummyDummy.foo(int, int)
             foo(1,2)                 );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DummyDummy().i.doIt();
}

}
```

Comment: It is a generated [synthetic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#isSynthetic())