# In Scala, is there a way to represent price as $Y.YY?

Tags: scala

At the moment, I'm thinking of representing price as follows:

```
case class Price(amount: Double)
```

Which allows me to do

```
val price = Price(4.52)
```

Is there any mechanism which would allow me to create a Price object as follows?

```
val price = $4.52
```

Comment: Note: never use floating point values for money.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Luigi Plinge shows how to get close, but *don't do this* because [the symbol `$` is reserved by the compiler/JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167326/java-class-name-containing-dollar-sign/6167369#6167369).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No because `$4` is a valid identifier and `.` signifies a method.

However you could say

```
val $ = Price
```

to set `$` equal to the price companion object and parenthetize the Double:

```
scala> val p = $(4.52)
p: Price = Price(4.52)
```

**edit**: another thing you could do would be:

```
scala> implicit def toDollar(d: Double) = new {
     |   def $ = Price(d)
     | }
toDollar: (d: Double)java.lang.Object{def $: Price}

scala> val p = 4.52 $
p: Price = Price(4.52)
```