# When should I use the dollar symbol ($) in a variable name?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

The dollar symbol ($) is a valid character to name a variable, e.g. `String superSecretFormula$;`, but when we're talking about naming conventions, when should I use this symbol?

Underscore for example is mostly used to separate words, as blank spaces can't be used.

Comment: Underscore is ONLY used when an expression is all uppercase; this is used to define constant values - i.e. when you use: static final

Comment: [You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification on identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The `$` character should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Comment: First, in Java '$' is a valid symbol for variable names and you can just use it for whatever you like: making your code cla$$ier, denoting that variables are private under a code convention, etc. Second, '$' is used as a separator character for the Java compiler to specify when a class is declared under another class. https://www.quora.com/What-does-mean-in-Java-3

Answer (score 18):

Theoretically you can use dollar sign in variable names, but it's strongly discouraged because  that symbol is used internally by the compiler(e.g. inner or anonymous classes's name).

Please refer to two related questions on the stackoverflow: [What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name) and [Java class name containing dollar sign fails to compile if an inner class is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167326/java-class-name-containing-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 14):

Your question is tagged Java, but it looks like you're asking about [type characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), which are still supported in Visual Basic but not widely used these days (nor for a long time).

This is a bit subjective, but I think it's fair to say: *never*

One scenario where you *might* want to prefix a variable name with `$` is when writing JavaScript code to [distinguish jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign).

### Edit

Regarding starting a variable name with a `$`, the [Oracle Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) tell us:

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "`$`", or the underscore character "`_`". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "`$`" or "`_`".

Comment: "This is a bit subjective, but I think it's fair to say: never" - actually, the Oracle java tutorial states explicitly that you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the first part of this response has to do with the question

Answer (score 5):

**Name conflicts with synthetic fields**

McDowell [quoted the JLS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057101/895245), here is an example that fails to compile on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 due to name conflicts with synthetic fields:

```
public class Assert {
    static final boolean $assertionsDisabled = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assert System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `javac` generates a field `$assertionsDisabled` to implement `assert`, which conflicts with our field, and `javac` says:

```
the symbol $assertionsDisabled conflicts with a compile synthesized symbol
```

See also: [What does the Java assert keyword do, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758224/what-does-the-java-assert-keyword-do-and-when-should-it-be-used/29439538#29439538)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that, in general, the use of the special symbol $ should be avoided, [as explained by Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056986/3114469). However, I remember seeing the use of $ to define a jQuery-like selector in the [reactor project](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/projectreactor/samples/EventBusSamples.java). I think that, used with caution, the $ symbol can help to define some beautiful APIs in Java.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, I use the "_" as a prefix to a private class-wide non-static variable or fields and "$" as a prefix to a private class wide static variable.

Its better than using the "m" prefix because it does not block the line of reading. You obviously would not begin to read the "_" or the "$" when you begin to read the variable word, right? Like ***_addressMap*** or ***$addressMap*** but with m like in Map ***mAddressMap*** it can be confusing at the point you are beginning to read it.

Although it is not conventional Java code, its a great help to mark those variable so you can understand them promptly if they are class-wide or not, or static or non-static. Of course you must discuss this to your teammate at first hand.