# Error: Type this$1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java

```
Type this$1 cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I can't resolve `ClamperListing.access$0(this.this$1).updateList();` in `ClamperListing$1$1.java`.
ClamperListing.Java is my main activity class

```
public class ClamperListing extends ListActivity
{

}
```

Comment: I don't think that using such notation is correct for Java... try renaming

Comment: Are you using this class inside an activity class?

Comment: `$` is used for inner classes. Why are you using it as your class name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java class name containing dollar sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167326/java-class-name-containing-dollar-sign)

Comment: then what is the solution can you explain me through example..

Comment: @ABFORCE Yes I am using this class inside an activity class

Comment: The `access$` members are helper methods emitted when an inner class attempts to access a private member of an outer class.  A good decompiler will attempt to restore the original member access, but there many be edge cases where it fails to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This notation usally come from executed (compiled) Java code.

If you get this you probably tried to execute code from reversed apk.

Anyway, when you get a YOURCLASSNAME.access$ this means is trying to assign the value to that member.

If you want more info take a look here and specially on the link on that page: [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/android-reverse-engineering-and-decompilation.html)

Hope that will help you :)