# Is a class within a class not counted as a class in Java?

Tags: java

***My Code***

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tutor tutorOne = new Tutor("Anthony Joshua", "Mathematics", "31", "London, England"); //creating tutor objects until "till here" comment
        Tutor tutorTwo = new Tutor("Andy Ruiz", "Physics", "31", "Mexico City, Mexico");
        Tutor tutorThree = new Tutor("Vitali Klitschko", "Computer Science", "49", "Saint Petersberg, Russia");
        Tutor tutorFour = new Tutor("Ray Leonard", "Mathematics", "64", "North Carolina, USA"); // till here
        Tutor[] allTutors = {tutorOne, tutorTwo, tutorThree, tutorFour}; // defining an Array containing all the tutors.
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); // user input
        System.out.println("Enter the subject: "); // the message user sees when program is run
        String tutorNeeded = userInput.toLowerCase().nextLine(); // reads input including the space between words
        for (int i = 0; i < allTutors.length; i++) { // for loop that iterates over allTutors
            Tutor t = allTutors[i];
            if (t.subject.contains(tutorNeeded)) {
                System.out.println(t.name + "\n" + t.subject + "\n" + t.age + "\n" + t.location); // prints all tutor attributes
            }
        }

        if (tutorNeeded.contains("math")) { // tutorNeeded.contains checks if these letters in this order is present in the user input
            System.out.println(tutorOne.name+"\n"+tutorOne.subject+"\n"+tutorOne.age+"\n"+tutorOne.location); // prints attributes for tutor one.
        }else if (tutorNeeded.contains("physics")) {
            System.out.println(tutorTwo.name+"\n"+tutorTwo.subject+"\n"+tutorTwo.age+"\n"+tutorTwo.location);
        } else if (tutorNeeded.contains(("computer"))) {
            System.out.println(tutorThree.name + "\n" + tutorThree.subject + "\n" + tutorThree.age + "\n" + tutorThree.location);
        } else if (tutorNeeded.contains("accounts")){
            System.out.println(tutorFour.name + "\n" + tutorFour.subject + "\n" + tutorFour.age + "\n" + tutorFour.location);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, we don't have any tutors for that subject available at this time.");
        }
    }
    static class Tutor { // defining second class
        String name; // defining properties of object tutors
        String subject;
        String age;
        String location;

        Tutor(String name, String subject, String age, String location) { // Tutor constructor to define objects used above
            // "this" refers to current instance of the current class
            this.name = name;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.age = age;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }
}
```

My University Professor says that this code has only one class. I understand that all the code is in one Main class, but wouldn't the Tutor Class also be counted as another class? Making it 2 classes in this code?

Comment: Your professor is wrong. (It has only one _top-level_ class.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Two classes, each compiled into their own file

Compile your code, and see for yourself. (After fixing that `toLowerCase` call.) Look at the files produced by the compiler.

The compiled code is in two files:

- `Main.class`
- `Main$Tutor.class`

Your `Tutor` class is [nested](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) within your `Main` class. That gets compiled using a joint name, combining outer class name and nested class name, separated by `$`. In your case, `Main$Tutor`.

➥ So, two classes here.

By the way, this nested-naming is the reason to avoid using `$` character in your Java naming. While allowed in some circumstances, its use can be confusing. Ex: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6167326/642706) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7484210/642706).

> My University Professor says that this code has only one class.

You likely misunderstood some other point your instructor was making.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You are correct.  This class has two classes, though only one is a top-level class.